# My android app is not working on Android 7

Tags: android, uri, android-7.0-nougat

I develop a camera android application, it works correct but when I run it in android 7, it creates a message which says "The app has stopped"! I think the problem is from this file of my code, it's my gallery file:

```
public class Gallery extends Activity {

GridView gv;
ArrayList<File> list;
Context context;
private static VirtualFileSystem vfs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery2);


    File f = new File("/myfiles.db");

    list = imageReader(f);

    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viewImage.class).putExtra("img", list.get(position).toString()));
        }
    });
}


class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageView iv;
    public Bitmap bmp = null;
    public File file ;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    class ViewHolder {

        ImageView icon;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");


        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);

        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
        iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
        new myTask(iv, file).execute();

        return convertView;
    }


    private class myTask extends AsyncTask <Void , Void ,Bitmap> {
        ImageView iv;
        File file;

        public myTask(ImageView iv, File file) {
            this.iv=iv;
            this.file= file;
        }



        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            try {
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {

            iv.setImageBitmap(aVoid);
        }
    }
}


ArrayList<File> imageReader ( File root) {

    final ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] files = root.listFiles();


    for (int i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {


        if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
            // input name directory to array list
            a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
        } else {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                a.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

In that link it uses "getUriForFile" but I think it cannot help me in this case!
Here is my logcat:

> 08-07 02:10:21.757 2343-2343/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack
>   module (No such file or directory) 08-07 02:10:21.757 2343-2343/?
>   E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2 08-07
>   02:10:21.913 2349-2349/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No
>   such file or directory) 08-07 02:10:21.913 2349-2349/?
>   E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2 08-07
>   02:10:22.220 2370-2370/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file:
>   Permission denied (13) 08-07 02:10:23.334 2390-2390/? E/memtrack:
>   Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) 08-07
>   02:10:23.334 2390-2390/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack
>   module: -2 08-07 02:10:23.708 2399-2415/? E/libEGL:
>   load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found 08-07
>   02:10:23.802 2399-2399/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.example.zeinab.amndoorbin, PID: 2399
>                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: cancel() called with a null
>   PendingIntent
>                                                        at android.app.AlarmManager.cancel(AlarmManager.java:890)
>                                                        at info.guardianproject.cacheword.CacheWordService.resetTimeout(CacheWordService.java:189)
>                                                        at info.guardianproject.cacheword.CacheWordService.attachSubscriber(CacheWordService.java:145)
>                                                        at info.guardianproject.cacheword.CacheWordHandler$2.onServiceConnected(CacheWordHandler.java:457)
>                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1453)
>                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1481)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 08-07
>   02:10:25.520 2399-2415/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 2415:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH) 08-07
>   02:10:25.612 706-1732/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1732:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/7746134

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your app configuration. change target api in project structure to api 25 refer [this link](http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/change-api-sdk-level-android-studio.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

After android M (api-23) you should asked user to accept required permission. you can do this by opening a dialog. here is sample code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(yourActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
```

and you can get the result of permission request by below code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults){
   switch (requestCode) {
       case 1: {

        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, 
            // contacts-related task you need to do.          
         } else {

            // permission denied
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }

    // other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this in my first page!